# Range of elementary embedding $\pi: V \rightarrow M$ models ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Let $V$ denote the cumulative hierachy and $M$ be a class together with an elementary embedding $\pi: V \rightarrow M$. As $\pi$ is elementary, we get that $im(\pi)$ models ZFC. But now my textbook claims that $M$ models ZFC, without mentioning that $\pi$ is onto. So, I wonder: Do we really get that $M$ models ZFC or do we indeed require $\pi$ to be onto?
If we need $\pi$ to be onto and you can refer me to a counterexample, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a special case of the definition of elementarity that $V\vDash \phi \leftrightarrow M\vDash \phi$, when $\phi$ is a sentence. Since every axiom of ZFC can be taken to be a sentence, and every axiom of ZFC is true (i.e. true in $V$), it follows that $M\vDash ZFC$.

Thus the embedding need not be onto in order to show that $M\vDash ZFC$. But, in fact, if the embedding is not the identity, it can't be onto. To see this, let $\pi$ be an elementary embedding from $V$ onto $M$ and let $x$ be an $\in$-minimal set such that $x \not= \pi(x)$. If $y\in x$, then $y = \pi(y)\in \pi(x)$. So $x\subseteq \pi(x)$. If $y\in \pi(x)$, then because $\pi$ is onto, $y = \pi(z)$ for some $z$. It follows that $z\in x$ and thus by the induction hypothesis, $z = \pi(z) = y\in x$. So $\pi(x)\subseteq x$.

Comment: Oh, I feel the need to apologize, because I already know all that you mentioned. I must have been half asleep, while asking the question. Thank you very much for your answer, though :-)

Comment: @Einer No worries!